# Transparancy issue on custom notification that displays on Android's lock screen

Tags: android, android-notifications, custom-notification

I'm currently working on a custom notification feature and have encountered a transparency issue with lock screen notifications on Samsung devices. When I set the transparency to High, it does make the notification on lock screen a little bit transparent (like 70%). However, unlike default Android notifications, the background doesn't fully transparent and the text color does not adjust automatically. I am attaching some screenshot for reference. I would greatly appreciate any suggestions or assistance to resolve this issue.

[image]
[image]

To set the background fully transparent and text color reversed